# Is it possible to use yaml's profile variable in spring mybatis's mapper xml?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

It is possible to use yaml's profile variable in spring mybatis's mapper xml?

If is it possible, how i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot do this in a simple way as both *.yml and *.xml files are loaded at application start-up time. Instead you can propagate values into placeholders within XML at build time using maven/gradle plugin.

E.g. for maven this can be done with [maven-resource-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html):

For example, if we have a resource `src/main/resources/hello.txt` containing

```
Hello ${name}
```

and a `pom.xml` with

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Upon calling `mvn resources:resources` will create a resource output in `target/classes/hello.txt` which contains:

```
Hello My Resources Plugin Practice Project
```

I.e. maven takes a value from `<name/>` tag and puts it into placeholder `${name}`.

Comment: Oh really? Can i show sample code to propate values into placeholders within xml?

Comment: @jabel123 I've updated my answer, see docs for maven-resource-plugin